# Gnosis Safe decoding of a delegated function call to a contract that is a proxy contract?

Tags: gnosis-safe, proxy-contracts

As explained in [this support](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4971390-submit-an-abi) article, Gnosis Safe will take a few hours to decode a pending transaction in its queue - assuming that the contract that is being called is verified on Etherscan (or equivalent). In my experience this is indeed what happens, however the decoding of transactions doesn't always happen. About 30 hours ago i delegated a transaction to a safe that calls a proxy contract - and so far the function has not been decoded.

Will Gnosis Safe decode transactions to proxy contracts (that have a verified implementation contract delegating the logic to)? Or will these types of transactions never be decoded because the implementation logic/code could change in the future? Is there a way i can have my transactions to this proxy contract decoded? I am building a product that uses gnosis safes and transaction delegation to this proxy contract and it would be helpful if the users of my product would be able to read the delegated function calls.

In the support article about decoding they request submitting the ABI of the contract in question - I am considering doing that - however I feel conflicted since technically the ABI I am submitting is of the implementation contract of the proxy, not the proxy itself (however in my case, it is sort of the same).

Appreciate the help! [This is the contract](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xd3d79a066f2cd471841c047d372f218252dbf8ed#code) in question I am delegating transaction to for the record(on Polygon mainnet): 0xD3D79A066F2cD471841C047D372F218252Dbf8Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe backend does not resolve proxies, so it's expected it's not decoded. One easy way to get the transaction decoded would be creating a transaction setting the master contract as `to` so it gets the information, then the function will be added to the database and will be decoded

Comment: Ah didn't know that - perfect will do that. Thanks a lot!